# What value does a static variable store when inputted into?

Tags: c++, c, variables, static, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *getname()
{
    static char name[30];
    scanf("%s",name);
    return name;
}

void main()
{
    char * name1,*name2;
    name1 = getname();
    name2 = getname();
    printf("%s %s\n",name1,name2);
}
```

**Input:** `Jack Jill`

**Output:** `Jill Jill`

I thought it should be Jack Jack since it stores the initial values inputted into it.

Comment: Generally, when static variables are initialised they hold onto that first intialisation.

Comment: You have a static array that is overwritten on each call. The last input is what you can read from it. (It is initialised to all bytes 0.)

Comment: I think perhaps you're confusing `static` with `const`.

Comment: Nope, I hadn't gotten it confused with const. Now I figured out why it happens. The function only returns the address of name which is a constant since C doesn't allocate separate memory for it. Therefore, name1 and name2 both point to name[30] at the end of initialization. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: What if I hadn't declared it as static?

Comment: If you hadn't declared it as static, then the `name` variable would go out of scope at the end of the function, and returning it would be Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name1` and `name2` point to the same object: the first element of `name`.

As both pointers `name1` and `name2` have the same value, it is normal when you print the array you get the same result.

The lifetime of a static object is the entire execution of the program and the address of a static object does not change during the execution of the program.

Comment: Thanks, really helped. One question though, what if I don't declare the name[30] variable as static? What if I just declare it as char name[30]?

Comment: If you don't declare name as static then it goes out of scope at the end of the function call and returning it from the function is a serious error.

Comment: Then `printf("%s %s\n",name1,name2);` would be undefined behavior. Without the `static` keyword, your array object would have automatic storage duration and its lifetime would end at the end of the `getname` function.

Answer (score 2):

A variable declared `static` inside a function body will retain its value across function calls. You can still change this value, though.

Answer (score 1):

In essense, a static variable (in this context, at the very least) is the same as a global variable, only that it can't be "seen" by code outside of the context where it's declared.

So, there is only ONE variabne `name` in your function, so each call to `getname` will overwrite whatever was in `name` last time. Hence when you call it a second time to fetch `Jill`, it overwrites the name `Jack`.

You could do, for example:

```
char name1[30], name2[30];
strcpy(name1, getname());
strcpy(name2, getname());
```

But my preferred solution would be to pass the `name` variable in:

```
char name1[30], name2[30];
getname(name1);
getname(name2);
```

and then remove the `char name[30];` in the function, and just have:

```
void getname(char *name)
{
   scanf("%s", name);
}
```

Much easier and no problem.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing is that this was an output question in a sample paper I was solving. I wasn't allowed to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one array of `char` in this code. That's the `static` array called `name`. At each call to `getname`, you fill the `name` array with the user's input. Then you return a pointer to the first element of this array (a `char*`). You store these returned pointers in `name1` and `name2`. They are both pointing at the same array. So when you `printf` each of `name1` and `name2`, you get the same output. That is, you get the characters that were last input into `name`.